# Why was this flag declined for a Spanish answer

Tags: discussion

It's been awhile, but it still bothers me.

A year ago I raised a flag "*Answer is not in English*" on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044556/932282) answer, because it was written in Spanish or Portuguese (sorry, can't tell the difference). The flag was declined however because:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

The [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4044556/revisions) clearly shows the moderator in question translated the answer to English, so why decline the flag?

Comment: because he translated it and it no longer had any problem

Comment: That sounds just like a mistake, not a malicious lie.  Also keep in mind that is an autogenerated message.

Comment: _It's been a while_ WTF?! One year is like a moment?

Comment: It could be that after she translated the answer, or even before, she hit the wrong button. You shouldn't assume the worst of people, and if this has been bothering you a while, you should have brought it up before. As bluefeet mentioned below, it's been long enough, and mods like her are kept busy enough, that she can't remember exactly what happened with that one specific flag a year ago.

Comment: Also worth note, if you're going to call a mod out on wrong-doing, a) Don't wait a full year (They likely won't remember what happened and be able to explain themselves) and b) have more/better examples. And more _severe_ examples.

Comment: ***somewhat off-topic*** I don't think that situation needs to involve a mod (especially not at first). Comment that posts should be in English (there is even a blurb in the help center about it you could link to), downvote if you wish, and close as 'unclear what you're asking'

Comment: Without trying to put words into anyone else's mouth, I will often decline a flag **where the action I took was something the flagger could have done themselves**. In this case you could have translated the answer yourself, if only by using an online translation tool.

Comment: I didn't want to use a online translation tool, because that could ruin the user's intend. I agree with Arun A.S that flagging it as Low Quality would have been better.

Comment: **No, of course not**; it's OK for them to make mistakes on occasion, though. *""Never ascribe to malice that which is adequately explained by incompetence"* (or, in this case, a very long list of flags to deal with!)

Comment: If the title of this question were something like "*Why was this flag declined for a Spanish answer*" there would be absolutely no problem with it.

Comment: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)... luckily, downvotes at MSO don't really impact reputation

Comment: @ChrisF I would honestly consider an attempt to translate answers via something like Google Translate to be a form of vandalism. You have no idea if the result is an accurate representation of the user's intent, and you're sticking them with ownership of the resulting reputation. Flagging was 100% appropriate in this instance

Comment: @ChrisHayes - you can leave the original language in place when you translate, or you can just leave a comment for the OP to translate. However, none of these actions are moderator specific. The only thing we can do that you can't is delete so a flag is still not the **first** thing you should do here.

Comment: @ChrisF Leaving the original language is clearly not helpful, though. Leaving a comment is nice, but you have a realistic chance they won't come back to address it. I'd probably leave a comment *and* flag, and assume that by the time somebody works their way through the queue to my flag, there will have been ample time for the poster to translate the answer. Realistically, if I comment and don't flag, I'm not going to remember to come back and flag later if it hasn't changed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, it's not ok for a moderator to lie or be dishonest.

However, I process a lot of flags and I can say that it was an honest mistake while using keyboard shortcuts when processing the flag.

I most likely translated the answer, then accidentally declined your flag. There was no dishonesty or lying involved here. It was a mistake.

Comment: Also, editing a single post is not a thing a moderator needs to be called for

Comment: You should have waited a year before answering this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One year ago I mailed you about this and you responded "Feel free to bring this to meta.". Which I now did and I'm happy with your answer. Let's move on.

Answer (score 27):

Once the answer was translated, it was not longer "not in English".

You seem to be overly concerned with how a single flag was handled.

And calling a moderator a liar over something so insignificant is petty and over the top.

Comment: The declining of the flag was obviously a mistake on my part.  I've got no clue why I did it considering it happened a year ago.

Comment: Is saying that someone told a lie really the same as calling them a liar?

Comment: @Gimby Yep, since the act of lying does make you a liar, just does not say how much of one.

Comment: @Gimby - doesn't it?

Comment: @Oded Not in my vocabulary in any case; one is something you do (and everyone does, for good and bad reasons), the other is something you are (and not everyone is)

Answer (score 13):

It definitely isn't honest for a moderator or any user to lie. However, this seems to be more of an honest mistake (at worst, really it just seems like the system misconstruing a situation) than a malicious lie.

I don't think this specific instance really warrants anyone's concern especially considering how long it took to even be brought up. A full year ago, and this was the only example of negative activity found? To me, that seems like exactly nothing.