# What's the minimum level of effort required to achieve the Jon-Skeet-Chrome-Bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

Hilariously, Jon Skeet has got such an unprecedented level of awesomeness that his in-line profile preview seems to overflow in my (1920px wide) monitor!!  It seems like he only has a rather pathetic 647 bronze badges... *but this is wrong by 1 order of magnitude!*

For an example, see the following (in Google Chrome only I think)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673866/2798367

I was wondering if there was an analytical solution for the minimum number of hours one has to pour into the site in order to be site-breakingly awesome...

> [image]

Comment: Are you zoomed in?

Comment: I am precisely 100%

Comment: What OS? What version of Chrome?

Comment: Skeet's been breaking the badge display for a while now, I'm pretty sure. EDIT: See [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges) for example.

Comment: Windows 10 TP / Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m

Comment: I can see his badge count just fine in all of its glory.  Xubuntu 14.10, 43.0.2357.18 beta

Comment: Hm. Ok my Xubuntu 14.10 / Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64bit) is fine...

Comment: At default zoom level it crops for me in Windows 8.1 42.0.2311.90 m -- You need 11 digits in your badge count. In any combination - it seems, but at least one of each.

Comment: I checked this and get the same problem ( but only when I'm 100% zoomed, no problem with other zooms ) I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate, Google chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m

Comment: @Kendra good spot.  Sorry I didn't see that post.  I assumed it only came about in the recent site changes

Comment: The only way to fix this would be to do something about Jon's name,  otherwise he will just break it again. We really need to contact Mr Skeet.

Comment: @ne1410s , you won't be able to achieve the Jon-Skeet-Chrome-Bug because by the time you reach close to it, Jon Skeet would have taken it to a whole new level.

Comment: @ArunA.S If I ever break 10k I'll be amazed :-D

Comment: Firefox 35, Linux, badges are cut off. Skeet should give me some of his badges...

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue because I do not have a four digit figure badge count.

Comment: The "Minimum" amount of effort solution would involve abuse of botnets (or a lot of patience on if you're on a dynamic IP address) to acquire badges in the publicist family. I imagine SE would identify such abuse and act against it though.

Comment: @johnpeters Jon skeet doesn't have the ability to delete anyone's posts except his own. He looks at it an the post deletes itself.

Comment: So:  `E = 1 / (M.b^2`)  then?  (Where E = effort, M = moderation safety coefficient, b = # botnets)

Comment: @TZHX, Afaik any 20k user can delete a zero vote question (I might be wrong here), Which means that he does not even have to look at it to delete it..

Comment: @jonascz it takes three 20k users to delete an answer I think (like it takes 3 10kers to delete a closed question).

Comment: I've just noticed that the `div.user-details` css selection that the area can withstand *in Windows / Chrome* before breaking onto the next line - is a seemingly irrational number.  I'm up to `153.0156173706054545px`

Comment: I'm up to `153.015617370605454539145284797996282577514px`. Still nothin'

Comment: `153.01561737060545453914528479799628257751464843749999999999999999999999999999999999999px`.  Though I'm guessing Chrome gives up placating me at 45 dp or so.

Comment: @JohnPeters Jon Skeet isn't even a diamond mod (though I imagine he could manage to be one, even without an election ;)). If he truly *deleted* your post, at least two other users agreed. If it was just closed, **four** other users agreed (unless he dupe-hammered it).

Comment: I can't see John Peters' comment, but I suspect he may have been referring to his -7 answer in [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291248/why-was-this-flag-declined-for-a-spanish-answer) which was heavily downvoted, and which I commented on - but which Oded deleted. (He has another couple of ranty answers in the same post...)

Comment: [Weird.](http://i.imgur.com/8tvftsT.png) Happens in Safari too.

Comment: This also happens firefox for me, seems consistent

Comment: Do I get a badge for my question being used as the example in the original post :)

Comment: [Here's a small .gif](http://i.imgur.com/fnfApJ7.gif) for anyone who can't reproduce the issue - this is Chrome 43.0 on Win7, zooming between 90% and 110%.